# Error when trying to use Database assembler

Tags: azerothcore

I'm on step 6 database setup on the installation tutorial and I've been encountering this error.

> Error 1045 (28000): Access Denied for user 'acore'@'localhost (using password: YES)
>
> Insert mysql user:

So this happens after I run `bash apps/db_assembler/db_assembler.sh` in the root of my folder as per told to. I've checked over everything to make sure the mysql user is acore and password to acore by default. I'm not changing it as this is only gonna be a LAN server, therefore there is no need to.

However I get this error so I enter

> insert mysql user:acore

then it asks for my pass

> insert mysql pass:

I try to enter it but it won't let me as shown in pic 1, I then press enter getting the error shown in pic 2

**Command Ran:** `bash apps/db_assembler/db_assembler.sh`

**Important Info:** OS: Windows 10 Home Edition, MySQL version 5.6.

[Image of Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgMFM.png)

[Image of Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROT2S.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL server must have user "acore" and you must grant access to "auth", "characters" and "wold" tadabases for this user.

If it is correct, check access to SQL servrer's port at firewall.